API data not getting passed through to main function because it is asynchronous
I am making a web site which displays the news data using reactjs.
This is my code:
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Chart from './components/chart';
import Headline from './components/headline';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

const apiUrl = `https://api.thenewsapi.com/v1/news/top?api_token=${apiKey}&locale=us&limit=1`

function apiCall(){
  fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(response => response.json())  // Parsing the JSON response
    .then(data => {
      var headlines = data.data[0].title;  // Handling the response data
      console.log(headlines)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);  // Handling errors
    });
}

function App() {

  var headlines = apiCall();;


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col><Chart></Chart></Col>
          <Col><Headline headline = {headlines}></Headline></Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I am successfully able to retrieve the data from the api by checking using a console.log, however I can't get the data into my App function, as the api is asynchronous. I have tried adding the async tag behind the api function but I am met with an error:

"Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

I am not passing an object, just a var (such as "new asteroid discovered next to earth!").
Any answers are appreciated.

You are doing a lot wrong.  Follow a tutorial that takes you through useState and useEffect, you will need both.  here is a different one.

apiCall doesn't return anything

read about useState and useEffect in react you have to use useState to update the Dom

apiCall returning anything didn't change anything either I still don't get an output.

Sorry about my english, i am learning. You are trying to make a request but the 'fetch' function returns a promisse but your app is trying to assign the response of 'apiCall' before the data is availabe.
Try to use this code:
//your imports...

const apiUrl = `https://api.thenewsapi.com/v1/news/top?api_token=${apiKey}&locale=us&limit=1`;

function apiCall() {
  return fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.data[0].title)
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

function App() {
  const [headlines, setHeadlines] = useState(''); //create a state here


  useEffect(() => {
    // await the response and set the state
    async function fetchHeadlines() {
      const headlineData = await apiCall();
      setHeadlines(headlineData);
    }

    fetchHeadlines();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col><Chart /></Col>
          <Col><Headline headline={headlines} /></Col> 
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


I am trying this solution, but I am still getting an empty output, probably from the async functions.
